# Заменить двойные кавычки в json_encode

Tags: javascript, php

На данный момент существует строка json_encode:

```
["55.763775,37.526462","55.773034,55.773034","55.743776,37.678128"]
```

Как можно заменить двойные кавычки " с обеих сторон чтобы они имели вид

```
[[55.763775,37.526462],[55.773034,55.77303],[55.743776,37.678128]]
```

С помощью JS или того же PHP

Comment: [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: @InDevX

Не получается именно привести к такому виду, заменяет только одну сторону, можно ли как-то привести банальный пример?

Comment: `str_replace(['["', ',"', '"'], ['[[', ',[', ']'], $jsonStr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или как то так

```js
const arr1 =
  ["55.763775,37.526462","55.773034,55.773034","55.743776,37.678128"];
const arr2 = arr1.map(item => [+item.split(',')[0],+item.split(',')[1]]);
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, исходные данные там не массив, а строка c JSON-представлением массива. Хотя могу и ошибаться.

Comment: Ну а я так понял. Что там не строка. Разницы нет особо. Главнепомочь

Answer (score 0):

На JS можно так:

```js
const str1 = '["55.763775,37.526462","55.773034,55.773034","55.743776,37.678128"]';
const str2 = str1.replace(/"(?=\d)/g, '[').replace(/(?<=\d)"/g, ']');
console.log(str2);
```

Или так:

```js
const str1 = '["55.763775,37.526462","55.773034,55.773034","55.743776,37.678128"]';
const str2 = str1.replace(/"([\d.,]+)"/g, '[$1]');
console.log(str2);
```

Но на тот случай, если вам нужно получить двумерный массив чисел из JSON, можно сразу так:

```js
const str1 = '["55.763775,37.526462","55.773034,55.773034","55.743776,37.678128"]';
const array = JSON.parse(str1).map(str => str.split(',').map(Number));
console.log(array);
```